# Android frame by frame method

Tags: android, video, frame, android-videoview

For a project, I have to do some operations on a Video frame by frame (like draw element on the Video). Are there methods that allow me to do operations frame by frame on Android?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the frames you can use the Android's frame-by-frame animation technique.

1. Put the images(frames) in the drawable folder.
2. Create a new file in drawable folder i.e., frames.xml
3. Then put this code in it

`<!-- Animation frames are wheel0.png through wheel5.png
     files inside the res/drawable/ folder -->
 <animation-list android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel0" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel3" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel4" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel5" android:duration="50" />
 </animation-list>`

4. Use an imageview to play those frames.

   ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.spinning_wheel_image);
    img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spin_animation);
    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();

   // Start the animation (looped playback by default).
    frameAnimation.start();

Reference.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

Comment: No, I have to do a REST request each frame of the video while the video is running